# MySQLの文字コードをutf8mb4に変更したが、絵文字がうまく入らない

Tags: php, mysql, database

PHP＋MySQLでWebアプリケーションを開発しています。
スマホからの絵文字がutf8では保存できないので、utf8mb4に変更しました。これでハートや太陽などは入るようになったのですが、人の顔のような絵文字は??になります。そこで、質問があります。

- utf8mb4でも、保存できる絵文字とできない絵文字が存在するのでしょうか。
- それとも、設定に不足か間違いがあって、本来全て保存できるものでしょうか？
- 保存できるものとできないものがある場合、違いは何でしょうか。見分ける方法等はありますか？

ぐぐっても回答が見つからず、困っております。情報へのポインタだけでも構いませんので、何卒よろしくお願いします。

追記：環境
CentOS6.5
Apache2.2.15
PHP5.6.12
MySQL5.5.28
フレームワーク 自作

my.cnfより抜粋

```
[mysqld]

# character-set
character-set-server=utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
#default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
default-character-set=utf8
```

php.ini内に特に文字コードの設定なし
（[mbstring]セクションはすべてコメントアウトされている）

Comment: 具体的にどの絵文字がOKでどの絵文字が駄目なのか、文字コードを特定して示せますでしょうか。あとWebサーバー含めて具体的にどのような環境で動かしているのか、バージョン等を明記されるとよいと思います。

Comment: 何文字か調べてみたところ、
&#9728;
&#10084;
&#10548;
などはOKで、
&#127381;
&#128516;
&#128517;
などが駄目でした。
サーバーCentOS6.5
Apache2.2.15
PHP5.6.12
MySQL5.5.28
です。
取り急ぎ。

Comment: 16進だとそれぞれ
OK
&#x2600;
&#x2764;
&#x2934;
NG
&#x1F195;
&#x1F604;
&#x1F605;
です。
これ、4バイト文字が入らないということですね。カラムをutf8mb4にしただけでは駄目で、MySQLの再起動などが要るのでしょうか。

Comment: character-set-server = utf8mb4にして再起動しましたがダメでした。

Comment: お手数ですが、質問本文を再編集する形で環境面等を追記ください。
また my.cnf や php.ini の文字コード絡みの設定部分も提示できますでしょうか。またphpウェブアプリは何かフレームワークを使われていますか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

utf8mb4 はすべての絵文字が入ります。

「?」になってしまうということは、テーブルやカラムの charset がちゃんと utf8mb4 になっていないか、クライアントからの接続が utf8mb4 になっていないということが考えられます。

接続の charset は `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'` クエリで確認できます。

接続の charset は接続毎に設定されるので、mysql コマンドで接続したときの charset がちゃんと utf8mb4 だったとしても、PHP アプリケーションからの接続では異なっている場合があります。

自分は PHP には詳しくないのですが、PHP アプリケーション内で MySQL 接続用の charset を指定できるパラメータがあると思いますので、それがちゃんと utf8mb4 になっているのかを確認してみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: PHPアプリケーションからMySQLへの接続が、utf8 になっていました。
これをutf8mb4 に変更することで動作しました。
ありがとうございました。